# to join the same table to match records from last year

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I want to create a join that joins records of last year to the same period of the current year. All the data is in the same table.

Input Table:

```
A  | B   | C  | D
a   2017   1    10
a   2017   2    20
a   2017   3     5
a   2016   1    100
a   2016   2    50
a   2016   3    1
```

Output Table:

```
A  | B   | C  | D   | E
a   2017   1    10    100
a   2017   2    20    50
a   2017   3     5    1
a   2016   1    100   NULL
a   2016   2    50    NULL
a   2016   3    1     NULL
```

Comment: Do a self LEFT JOIN!

Comment: @jarlh on what? i want the current year to join with previous year. So when i use left join output table on b=b-1 it doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this.  One is a `left join`:

```
select t.*, tprev.d as e
from t left join
     t tprev
     on t.a = tprev.a and t.c = tprev.c and tprev.b = t.b - 1;
```

Another way is to use window functions:

```
select t.*, lag(t.d) over (partition by t.a, t.c order by b) as e
from t;
```

These work on the same on your data.  But they are subtly different.  The first looks specifically at the data one year before.  The second looks at the most recent year before where there is data.